# Shortest word in the Torah

Tags: words, riddle, torah-reading

What is the shortest word in the Torah?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

הַאֲזִינוּ פרק לב פסוק ו

**הַ** לְיְהוָה, תִּגְמְלוּ-זֹאת

Comment: I don't understand how this answer could be accepted without any source justifying that this is actually a word.

Comment: @Curiouser - Note the usernames.

Answer (score 6):

There are a number of words of two letters, which could all count as the shortest.

But according to the Ibn Ezra, the heh which begins Devarim 32:6 is connected to the lamed and is not a word on its own. This is a famous mechlokets. See [a nice video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O76f5ZgDIjs) on the topic here.